# What could be the cause for this performance difference?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-mapped-files

I'm constructing a cache file(~70MB for test) meant for spinning drives, there is a lot of random IO involved since I'm sorting things into it, somewhat alleviated by caching sequential items but I also have memory constraints.

Anyways, the difference appears between when I

a) freshly create the file and write it full of data ~100s

b) open the same file and write it full of data ~30s

I'm using memory mapped files to access them, when I freshly create a file I preallocate of course. I verified all the data, its accurate.

The data I'm writing is slightly different each time (something like 5% difference evenly distributed all over). Could it be that when I write to a mmf, and I overwrite something with the same data, it doesn't consider it a dirty page and thus doesn't actually write anything at all? How could it know?

Or perhaps there is some kind of write caching going on by windows or the hardware?

Comment: Do you do sorting during your "write it full of data"? You should probably show the code your measuring on. If that is the main issue, try preallocating by writing out zeroes to the actual file, then opening it with your memory mapped mode and see if that is indeed faster than your current preallocation scheme. Note that writing out 70 MB of data (sequentially) should take you about 23ms (@3GB/s).

Comment: There is no real scenario where creating a 70 MB file can take a hundred seconds.  Except one, disable anti-malware and try again.

Comment: You guys seem to be oblivious to the fact that random IO into a file on a spinning HDD is lucky to get above a couple megabytes per second but anyways, I have made a discovery. If I fill the file with 0's sequentially before sorting data into it, the difference goes away and both options take the same amount of time. I'm suspecting that when I set the file pointer in windows, it doesn't really allocate but just pretends it does, writing 0's forces it to really allocate.

Comment: Extending a file does allocate space, but doesn't zero it.  If you write to a random location in a brand new file, that forces Windows to write all the zeros from the start of the file to the location you're writing.  The difference you're seeing still seems excessive to me, maybe something to do with caching, but preparing the file in advance is a perfectly reasonable step.  (You don't need to explicitly zero the entire file, though, just writing a zero byte at the end of the file will have the same effect.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to trace [the page faults](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965225(v=vs.85).aspx). Or at least, try to monitor the page faults with process explorer for each write phase.

Anyway, when you open the same file with write access, the file is "recreated", but in memory the existing mapped paged are kept as it. Then, during the writing, if the data is binary the same inside a whole page (usually 4k per page so statistically this can happen with your data), the content of the page will not be flagged as "updated". So when closing file, no flush occurs for some pages that's why you see a big difference of performance.